# typeof undefined not working with .get() within variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm using `.get()` in a variable which returns `'undefined'` until I deselect items in multiple select options.

I tried to avoid this with a condition typeof but it still returns undefiend when selecting new options.

```
var $slidesoptions = $('#Slidesnumber');
var $deselected = $slidesoptions.find('option.selected:not(:checked)');
$slidesoptions.find('option:checked').addClass('selected');
$deselected.removeClass('selected');

if(typeof $deselected.get()[0].value === "undefined"){
    console.log("its undefined");
}
else {
    console.log("its not undefined");
    console.log("$deselected:",$deselected.get()[0].value);
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'value')

**UPDATE:** I think i found it, I need to check only for the array, not the value in the array, not exactly sure why though.

```
if(typeof $deselected.get()[0] !== "undefined"){
console.log("its not undefined");
}
```

Comment: Just check the length. You are making it way more complicated. `if ($deselected.length) {  }`

Comment: Great thanks, that works as well. Just wondering why `.get()[0].value` was still causing undefined.

Comment: `undefined != "undefined"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: The difference is that if `[0]` returns `undefined`, you can't access its `.value` property, so you get an error at that intermediate stage. It never gets to the point of getting the type of `value`.

Comment: You could use optional chaining: `typeof $deselected.get()[0]?.value === "undefined"`

Comment: @epascarello They're using `typeof`, which returns a string.